# Code optimization to remove nested Subscribe in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a following scenario inside subscription.add. I dont want nested subscribe. Any Suggestion.I want to check that both Firstvalue and SecondValue data is available to dispatch an action.

```
this.subscription.add(
  this.store.select(FristState?.firstValue).subscribe(() => {
    this.store.select(SecondState?.secondValue).subscribe((secondValue) => {
      console.log(secondValue)
    });
  })
);
```

Comment: The equivalent is `combineLatest` https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `combineLatest` which will emit a value for each new one

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest

Your code equivalent from what you posted would be

```
this.subscription.add(
  combineLatest([
    this.store.select(FirstState?.firstValue),
    this.store.select(SecondState?.secondValue)
  ]).subscribe(([firstValue, secondValue]) => {
    console.log(secondValue);
  })
);
```

Note this will emit for every new value of `FirstState` and `SecondState` as your example code did because redux stores are `BehaviorSubjects`